# How to change a DHCP's Scope Subnet - Windows Server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, dhcp-server

I am trying to edit my DHCP Scope and want to Change only Subneting. The Reason I am searching for this is "I am using MAC Addresses in Policies". I have tried this solution http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/8484.how-to-easily-change-a-dhcp-s-scope-subnet.aspx.
When I try to run this command `netsh exec C:\dhcp.txt` , its giving me an error that

```
PS C:\DHCP_Backup> netsh dhcp server \\DC2 Scop 192.168.10.0 dump  >C:\DHCP_Backup\dhcp.txt
PS C:\DHCP_Backup> netsh exec C:\DHCP_Backup\dhcp.txt
The following command was not found:  ■.
```

I have make sure that there must be no white space in beginning of the file but even then, its giving error. Please guide / help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check the file with notepad++, a bad format in the file.

Thanks for using my article by the way.